# Combination of remoting and clustering

Tags: quartz.net

I am quite new to Quartz.NET, but was able to create a running solution for my problem.
There are remote server instances, which are executed as windows services. The jobstore for these instances is an AdoJobStore with SQLLite backend.
The client application is able to run jobs remotely through remote scheduler proxies.

Now i have to combine the remote execution with clustering. Right here I am struggling with the instantiating of scheduler proxies for remote servers. When a scheduler is created on client, side addresses and ports are configured explicit with the properties of the scheduler factory.

In architecture with a cluster consisting of several remote services and one client, which has to start jobs on these servers with the Quartz.NET feature load balancing, an explicit start of each of the jobs to a specific server address makes no sense to me.

1. So, how should the client app give the jobs to the cluster and how has the cluster to be configured (for example a list of server ip addresses and port to be used)?
2. In addition: how have the Quartz.NET server instances to share the database and how will this work for server less SQLLite?

Thanks for any tip useful for further reading I have to do,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I was able to get my system to work. The answer to my question “Combination of remoting & clustering” is: Do not combine these features, as it is not necessary.

1. For implementation of a distributed cluster, don’t use remoting at all (hard to find when your first development step was creating a client with a single remote server).
   Distribution of jobs and therefore all “connecting” of instances is done by using the same database, which has to be centralized for that reason (using SQL Express now).
2. Don’t start your local (client) scheduler instance.
3. Don’t care about all the local working threads appearing even when all the work should be carried out by the remoted servers in the cluster. My expectation would have been to use a scheduler with 0 threads in the local application, as you do not want to start any job within this app.
4. Problem unsolved: There seems to be no way to register a listener which will be called when a job is executed in the cluster. So I have to build my own feedback channel job --> starting app in order to track the status of jobs (start time, finish time, node where execution has taken place, ..).
5. Unsolved problem: When the local (WPF) application is closed by the user an endless loop in SimpleThreadPool

   ```
   while (runnable == null && run)
   {
       Monitor.Wait(lockObject, 500);
   }
   ```

   prevents the process from being exited.